# Как правильно получить контекст для доступа к строковым ресурсам?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть отдельный класс, предоставляющий данные для адаптера. Я создал ссылку с именем контекст, но как сделать так, что бы она соответствовала контексту? Я пытаюсь получить доступ к строковым ресурсам внутри класса.

```
public class MyListItem
{
Context context;
private String liters;
private String volume = context.getResources().getString(R.string.Volume_unit);

public void setLiters(String liters)
{
    this.liters = liters;
}

public String getLiters()
{
    return liters + volume;
}

public static MyListItem fromCursor(Cursor cursor) 
{listitem.setLiters(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase.COLUMN_LITERS)));
return listitem;
}
}
```

Comment: мне кажется вы делаете что-то не то. Вычисление поля `volume` стоит перенести в конструктор класс, туда же передавать `context`, пока у вас выглядит как `NPE`. И да, что такое `listitem`?

Comment: @pavel `listitem` класс который передаёт в адаптер данные полученные от курсора,  я просто получаю из бд число и хочу подписать к нему единицы измерения, записанные в файле `strings`, что бы в `TextView` выводилось число + ед. измерения

Comment: Откуда (из какого класса) вы вызываете метод `getLiters()`?

Comment: @eugeneek из курсор адаптера, метод `onBindViewHolder` `((ViewHolder0) viewHolder).liters0.setText(myListItem.getLiters());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз метод, в котором нужен `Context` вызывается из метода `onBindViewHolder` адаптера, то можно получить контекст из корневой вью и передать непосредственно в нужный метод. А лучше даже просто ресурсы, так как весь контекст там не нужен:

```
Resources res = viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources();
((ViewHolder0) viewHolder).liters0.setText(myListItem.getLiters(res));
```

Ну и сам метод будет выглядеть так:

```
public String getLiters(Resources res) {
    return liters + res.getString(R.string.Volume_unit);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, это то что нужно! Все работает

Answer (score 2):

Советую избегать хранения `Context`  в членах класса.

В вашем случае, я бы поступил так:

```
public String getLiters(Context context) {
    return liters + context.getString(R.string.Volume_unit);
}
```

**P.S.** `Volume_unit` - немножко нарушает *naming convention*, надо или `volumeUnit` или `volume_unit`